# Convex hull of union of nondisjoint polyhedra

Tags: convex-analysis, polyhedra, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

Is there a theorem which proves that the convex hull of the union of nondisjoint polyhedra is also polyhedral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the individual polyhedra are given by $\{ x : A^i x \leq b^i\}$, the convex hull of their union is: $$\{ x : x = \sum_i \lambda_i x^i,  A^i x^i \leq b^i, \sum_i \lambda_i = 1, \lambda \geq 0\}.$$
Since the projection of a polehedron onto an affine set ($x^i$ and $\lambda$ are projected out) is polyhedral, the set above is polyhedral.

Comment: thank you for your help